# Running a public static void main in Groovy Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy

Sorry Groovy Noob here:

Here is my Groovy Class -

```
class MyClass {
    static void main() {
        println("Hello World");
    }
    ...
```

How do I run this classin Eclipse STS?  I want to keep the main method.  I do not want to change this to just a script.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To initiate a method, main you must pass in a string array (String[] something). Use the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
System.out.println("Hello World")!
}
```

Comment: Thanks I just did static void main(args)

Answer (score 1):

Remember... a Groovy class *is* a Java class.  All you need to do is right-click -> Run as -> Java application.

Comment: Using Kepler i do no see that option

Comment: Best off to create a new question and include the groovy class/script you are working with.